# Performing Latent Profile Analysis on unordered data with by-item variability

Tags: clustering, latent-variable

We would like to identify latent classes within our subjects. In our experiment, each subject sees 6 different items out of 24. Each response is an integer on the scale 0-100.

**For example:**
Subject A may have the following answers: item 1: 70, item 2: 85, item 3: 40, etc.
Subject B: item 7: 50, item 8: 90, item 9: 82, etc.
In this example, subjects A and B do not see any of the same items.

Since subjects did not see all the items but just a subset of 6 items, we cannot form our dimensions as a response to each particular item (item1, item2, …, item24). What we tried was
forming dimensions based on the order in which subjects saw the items in the experiment (item they saw first, item they saw second,..., items they saw the sixth)
calculating the mean score (thus LPA on one dimension: mean score per subject)

The problem of the first method is that LPA captures order effects which we are not interested in. In the second method, we lose quite a bit of variance in each subject. Importantly, there is variability in items themselves which is ignored in both of the above methods but we don’t know if it is possible to include it in LPA.

**Is there some method (e.g. a variant of LPA) which allows to do EITHER of the following:**

- find latent classes not based on dimensions but rather on an unordered set of answers
- account for variability in items. E.g., we thought about passing to LPA a table that would have 24 columns, and for each row (e.g., subject) there are scores only for a subset of 6 items, but for the other 18 it is undefined (e.g., NA or some negative value).